# script tags not loading VisualStudio 2015 and Angular.js app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

I made an empty web project ( no need for MVC here, but oddly I feel uncomfortable without the folders ) and Added Angular.Js Core

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

after my title in HTML head. For some reason it does not find my local copy of angular.Js yet using an web reference seems to work perfectly

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
```

works perfectly ?

Why would my local be non functional ? ( how would I debug this ? )

edit : wow I just realized how basic this question is , so yes the Scripts are in the Scripts folder.

Comment: Are you loading this in IIS proper, or IIS Express? I seem to recall a setting in IIS that stopped the root `~` flag from working

Comment: where do you place the index.html? are you using a <base> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `~` character in the src attribute of (client-side) HTML elements. It can only be used in ASP.NET (server-side) controls, such as a ScriptManager or HyperLinks.

In your case you might want to use something like this:

```
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/angular.js") %>'></script>
```

Although, this will only work in ASP.NET pages/controls, not in HTML pages.

If you have an HTML page, the just remove the `~` character and put a valid relative URL, e.g. `src="../scripts/angular.js"`.

Comment: Thanks for the info this is great.